# I don't get the $.connection.[hubName]

Tags: websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I try to add web socket functionality using signalR, based on :
the [chat example](http://www.dispatchertimer.com/signalr/signalr-tutorial-a-simple-chat-application-using-signalr-and-angularjs/).

I have 2 different project - 
**1:**  is pure server, includes web api:
I have a web method to get the request and call to hub:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/GetData")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCorpDataApi()
    {
        return Ok(getResponse());
        **startWebSocket();**
    }
```

the start web socket method calls to:

```
private void startWebSocket()
    {
        MonitorHub hub = new MonitorHub();
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(hub.DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 3000;
        myTimer.Start();
    }
```

that calls to a method in my hub:

```
public class MonitorHub : Hub
{

    public void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var response = MonitorUtils.GetCorpData();
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(response);
    }

}
```

(All is in the same project, compiled with no errs).

My client code is located in the client angular project (also under VS),
I added the required functionality within the controller:

```
function initWebSocket() {
          self.chatHub = null; // holds the reference to hub
          self.chatHub = $.connection.MonitorHub; // **I dont have MonitorHub**
          $.connection.hub.start(); 
          self.chatHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (response) {
              //bla bla
          };              
      }
```

I want to mention that I included in the index.html the files:

```
<script src="scripts/Vendor/jquery/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>                                                              
<script src="scripts/Vendor/jquery/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

$.connection.MonitorHub gets nothing - undefined.

**I really believe that it has something to do with the fact that the server side
is in a different project than the client side. When I run a simple example like the chat example, it works - all in the same project.**

I get in the console this error:
**Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. .**

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it might be a case of `JQuery` version mismatch. Try using a lower jquery version e.g. jquery-1.6.4.js

Comment: Thanks, but It's not the case.
I still get error in the console of:
Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.

Comment: ok. Check whether you are having any resource path mismatch issue with the js files.

Comment: That's a SignalR generated file. Can you check if it's available by appending  "signalr/hubs" to your localhost path?

Comment: it is not exist :-(

Comment: Your import statement might be this instead :  <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

Comment: ok that's an improvement - I see now the signalr/hubs in the localhost !
but I still get error of "Cannot read property 'client' of undefined" since
$.connection.MonitorHub is undefined :-(

Comment: SignalR supports jquery up to 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You did not seem to have added SignalR server to your project. You seem to be starting a WebSocket and create an instance of a hub and throwing some Web API. This is not how SignalR works. You need to install SignalR server packages to your server and then SignalR will take care of handling your calls, instantiating your hubs etc. Just follow the tutorial you posted a link to (*Setting up the project* section) or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for your reply.
I went thru the post I added and I added the SignalR to server side 
using nuget.
The server is running and initializing well.
BTW I have a working eaxmple in which the client and the server are in the same project.
Here the difference is that the server is in one project and the client in another.
Any other idea ? 
Thanks !

Comment: If your javascript comes from a different server than the one the SignalR is running on you need to enable CORS. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) is a tutorial in which they do something similar - signalR server is self hosted but html containing javascript files are served from a separate server.